# Editing a sent message in chat -- colours are confusing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

#### Procedure:

1. Go into a chat room.
2. Send a message.
3. Go to message actions for the one you've just sent.
4. Hit "Edit".

Both the message and your text box turn grey.

#### Why this is confusing:

I don't know where to look. I would have expected I could put the mouse cursor in the message that is in the chat, but the cursor doesn't work there. Down below the chat area turns grey and that's the correct place to edit your message.

Colours changed, my eye focus is split into two areas, the one I instinctively wanted to use was wrong.